# Close and save workbook via macro without running 'beforesave' events

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of workbooks that follow the same template, and all have a macro 'beforesave' event, which basically creates a save-log in on of the sheets, listing the time and user id from whoever is saving the workbook.

So sometimes I need to change a formula in all workbooks, and since it takes around a minute to close and save each of them manually, I created a macro that opens all of them changes what I need changed, and closes saving them. That would save me some significant amount of time, as on total this process ends up taking around 30 mins of my time, and a lot of boredom.

Problem is: when the macro tries to close and save the workbook, the 'beforesave' event doesn't run properly and as a result the workbook doesn't save and close with the macro. For some reason, the event seems to be skipped in the macro...

To solve that I want to run this macro to make all the changes in all workbooks, skipping the beforesave event (if necessary) and actually saving and close them at the end.

Help please?

Tried running the macro line by line, and when it gets to the event part, it calls it, but for some reason it stays in the same sheet instead of going to the log sheet, and writes the log info in the wrong sheet as a result. In any case, running line by line won't obviously work for me as it's basically the same as doing the process myself, manually.

```
Sub DoStuff()
    Dim Row As Integer
    Dim Col As Integer
    Dim wbCopy As Workbook
    Dim wbPaste As Workbook
    Dim wbBP As Workbook

    For Col = 4 To 4
        ThisWorkbook.Activate
        Set wbBP = Workbooks.Open(Cells(1, Col), False)
        ThisWorkbook.Activate
        Set wbCopy = Workbooks.Open(Cells(2, Col), False, True)

        For Row = 3 To 19
            ThisWorkbook.Activate
            SetAttr Cells(Row, Col), vbNormal
            Set wbPaste = Workbooks.Open(Cells(Row, Col), False)
            wbCopy.Activate
                Sheets("Base").Activate
                Range("A7:EQ500").AutoFilter
            wbPaste.Activate
                Sheets("Base").Activate
                Range("A7:EQ500").AutoFilter
            wbCopy.Activate
                Sheets("Base").Activate
                Range("AL8:AS8").Copy
            wbPaste.Activate
                Sheets("Base").Activate
                Range("AL8:AS" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            wbPaste.Close True
            ThisWorkbook.Activate
            SetAttr Cells(Row, Col), vbReadOnly
        Next Row
        wbCopy.Close False
        wbBP.Close False
    Next Col

End Sub
```

Running the macro to do the changes I need, and having all workbooks involved saved and closed properly.

Comment: You might benefit from reading 
[Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613)

Comment: *for some reason it stays in the same sheet instead of going to the log sheet, and writes the log info in the wrong sheet as a result* - this looks very very much ilke a consequence of relying on `.Activate` and coding against implicit `ActiveSheet` references; see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/1188513). Basically instead of `wbPaste.Activate` then `Sheets("Base").Activate` then `Range(...)`, you'd do `wbPaste.Sheets("Base").Range(...)`, i.e. qualifying `Range` and `Cells` calls with a proper `Worksheet` object instance.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the `BeforeSave` event handler code; seems very much like that's the code that needs to be fixed (plus the `.Activate` going on in *this* code). Also, clarifying whether the event handlers run or not would be a good thing, too. hit F9 to set a breakpoint in a handler, run the code. If the breakpoint is hit, the event is fired.

Comment: if `BeforeSave` events of all the workbooks  are accessible to you, may simply introduce  checking  of a cell value to a desired code to go through or to bypass the event. Also make `open`.event to  set the value. And after opening the the workbook from your macro,reset the cell value to bypass the before save event.

Comment: Also the title is confusing, it reads as though you *don't* want the handlers to run - but then I gather from the post body that you *do* want them to run, but they don't. Or they actually do, but not correctly. Please clarify, we can help you fix this!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. The answer to the title is too simple if you are OK to execute your update job running any events in the `wbPaste` workbooks.  Just simply adding `Application.EnableEvents = False` before the saving the file and make it true after the save completion.

Also based on the points commented  by @Mathieu Guindon your post is confusing about your exact requirement and the inadvertent use of `Activate` I just restructured your code a little to avoid running any events during update.

```
Sub DoStuff()
    Dim Row As Integer
    Dim Col As Integer
    Dim wbCopy As Workbook
    Dim wbPaste As Workbook
    Dim wbBP As Workbook

‘Worksheet name “FileList” used for trial . May please change to yours  or use activesheet 
 With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FileList")    
       For Col = 4 To 4
       ‘Could not understand why wbBP opened, it is not used anywhere in the code 
       Set wbBP = Workbooks.Open(.Cells(1, Col), False)
        Set wbCopy = Workbooks.Open(.Cells(2, Col), False, True)

       ‘ This will disable any events including ‘BeforeSave’ events
        Application.EnableEvents = False
       ‘Disabling  ScreenUpdating  will increase efficiency if large files used
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

          For Row = 3 To 19
            SetAttr .Cells(Row, Col), vbNormal           ‘ failed to understand use of SetAttr
            Set wbPaste = Workbooks.Open(.Cells(Row, Col), False)
            wbCopy.Sheets("Base").Range("A7:EQ500").AutoFilter
            wbPaste.Sheets("Base").Range("A7:EQ500").AutoFilter
            wbCopy.Sheets("Base").Range("AL8:AS8").Copy
            wbPaste.Sheets("Base").Range("AL8:AS" & Cells(Rows.Count , 1).End(xlUp).Row).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            wbPaste.Close True
            SetAttr .Cells(Row, Col), vbReadOnly
        Next Row
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        wbCopy.Close False
        wbBP.Close False
    Next Col
    End With
End Sub
```

**If you want to run other events in the wbPaste workbooks and only intend to avoid running only BeforeSave events or a part of code in that event and you have access to modify the event codes**, then you may resort to introduce a branch in the `BeforeSave’ events code by checking value of cell as per my comment.  If apprehensive about cell value being accidentally modified/deleted by user, it is better to introduce check a ‘CustomDocumentProperties’

You may opt to add & set the custom Document Property from document  panel of all the `wbPaste` workbooks. I would prefer to introduce the Custom Document Property `BeforeSaveCheck`‘ by onetime running the code

```
Sub testOnce()
    Dim Row As Integer
    Dim Col As Integer
    Dim wbPaste As Workbook
    Col = 4

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FileList")
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For Row = 3 To 19
            SetAttr .Cells(Row, Col), vbNormal
            Set wbPaste = Workbooks.Open(.Cells(Row, Col), False)
            wbPaste.CustomDocumentProperties.Add Name:="BeforeSaveCheck", LinkToContent:=False, Type:=msoPropertyTypeBoolean, Value:=True
            wbPaste.Close True
            SetAttr .Cells(Row, Col), vbReadOnly
        Next Row
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Now you may introduce the a simple branch in `BeforeSave` events of wbPaste workbooks like

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

If ThisWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties("BeforeSaveCheck") Then
‘’’’’’’’’’’’’
‘The code section you want to bypass while updating with macro
‘’’’’’’’’’’’
End If

End Sub
```

and setting the property to True at the open event

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
ThisWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties("BeforeSaveCheck") = True
End Sub
```

Finally in    `sub dostuff` 
Delete lines

```
   Application.EnableEvents = False
   Application.EnableEvents = True
```

And add line

```
ThisWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties("BeforeSaveCheck") = False
wbPaste.Close True
```